Why does my "Game" tab show images with grayish/wrong colors while my "Scene" tab correctly shows images with correct colors in Unity?
I create a Unity project.
The "Scene" tab shows the image with the correct colors.
But, the "Game" tab shows the image with a grayish colors, which are the wrong colors.

Here is the mage from the "Scene" Tab, which has the correct colors :


Here is the image from the "Game" Tab, which shows the wrong colors:



I guess there is something wrong in my setting or configuration for colors or lighting.
Can you please tell me how to fix this ?
Thanks.

Do you have any post processing filters active? This looks a lot like a colourblindness simulation mode — is it possible you or someone on your team was checking for colourblind accessibility and forgot to disable the filter afterward?

@DMGregory, You are right. Thanks for your input. Someone attached a script to the camera to do some special color transitioning from 1 scene to another. This scripts accidentally caused a bug as described above.

Excellent. Want to write that up as an Answer below to help future readers grappling with similar problems know what to check and how to remove it?

@DMGregory, I added the answer as you suggested. Thanks.

Per a suggestion from user @DMGregory , I posted this answer below.

Here are my 2 steps to solve the issue:

First, I looked at Unity Settings for Scene, Environment, Realtime
Lightmaps, and Baked Lightmaps. But, everything looked fine.

Second, I looked at the camera to see if it incorrectly changed the colors in the "Game" tab.
I found out that someone attached a script to the camera to do some
special color transitioning from 1 scene to another. This script
accidentally caused a bug as described above. I removed this script,
and the problem was solved.


